# How can I make a Jest test ensure that a value is in an enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, jestjs, ts-jest

This is my first time working with jest. I have a scenario where I want to see if the selected value is in an enum or not. Here is my test case:

```
    test('Should be valid', () => {
        expect(TestCasesExport.userAccStatus(ACC_STATUS.LIVE)).toContain(MEM_STATUS);
    });
```

`MEM_STATUS` is an enum and `ACC_STATUS` is another enum that has some common values with MEM_STATUS.

When I run this test the **received** is `'live'` and expected was an object i.e. `{"LIVE": "live", ...}`.

So, what do I change in my test case so that I can ensure that the **received** value is present in the enum `MEM_STATUS`?

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same issue. Checking an objects values `expect.any(SomeEnum)` will fail with:

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable'
```

Hopefully jest improves this in future, however here's a **workaround** allowing you to ensure that a value is in an Enum:

```
// We can't do expect.any(Currency)
// So check the value is in the enum (as an Object)'s values
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697466/jest-test-to-ensure-that-a-value-is-in-an-enum
const knownCurrencies = Object.values(Currency);
expect(knownCurrencies.includes(currency));
```

Elsewhere (eg in object values tests) you'll just have to test that the value is a Number, but the previous code will ensure it appears in the enum.

```
expect(lastTransaction).toEqual({
  ...
  // expect.any(Currency) won't work
  currency: expect.any(Number),
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a helper function `expectEnum`:

```
const expectEnum = <T extends { [key: string]: string }>(enumType: T) =>
    expect.stringMatching(Object.values(enumType).join('|'));
```

And an example:

```
enum ESomeEnum {
    black = 'black',
    white = 'white',
}
expect({ type: ESomeEnum.black }).toMatchObject({ type: expectEnum(ESomeEnum) });
```

> Modify this helper fn for your purposes if needed

> Jest [expect.stringContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringcontainingstring) docs